# Como faço para emular uma aplicação do ionic 2 no tablet, e também como gero um .ipa e .apk?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, angular

Estou querendo emular minha aplicação ionic 2 no tablet mas nao consigo, já fiz um upload no ionic cloud mas so funciona em celulares o aplicativo ionic view, também usei o ionic emulete e o ionic run, mas quando abre o emulador do Ipad da tela branca, o que eu faço? Teria uma outra opção? E como eu emular minha aplicação para o android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Verifica se o teu aparelho android está com as opções de desenvolvedor habilitadas. Se não estiver, tu pode seguir este passo a passo para habilita-las: http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2014/10/como-ativar-o-modo-desenvolvedor-no-android.html;
- Nas opções de desenvolvedor, tu tem que habilitar a depuração usb, conectar teu aparelho no computador, e executar o "ionic run android".
- Sobre a tela branca que você está tendo no tablet, você pode entrar no debugger do google chrome e verificar se existe algum erro de script na aplicação. Digite chrome://inspect/ no navegador e em "Remote Target" seu aparelho vai estar listado. Clique em inspect device para abrir o debugger.
- Pra gerar os arquivos para android, tu pode executar o comando "ionic build android", e para ios, "ionic build ios", porém, a compilação para ios tem que ser feita de um macbook.

Comment: então eu usei o comando ionic build ios, mas ele me gera um arquivo .app, e no casa eu preciso de um .ipa para ios, e eu estou usando um mac

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse fórum no site do ionic, acho que vai ter ajudar https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-generate-an-ios-ipa-file-with-ionic/9873/2

Comment: eu fiz o que vc falo, mas quando emula no meu tablet que é um android, da tela branca, sendo que eu habilitei a opção de desenvolvedor

Comment: na verdade, o que você tem que fazer é entrar no debugger do google chrome, e verificar se existe algum erro de script na tua aplicação, como eu falei ali no tópico 3.

Comment: quando eu abri o chrome://inspect/  para ver o erro me apareceu esse erro:

Comment: Error in ./MyApp class MyApp - inline template:16:2 caused by: Connection is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Cara sua pergunta é muito genérica,
Bem recomendo a leitura da documentação do ionic que explica detalhadamente o passo a passo para deployar a sua aplicação tanto no Android, como no iOS.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/deploying/